# How to extract cell values in one wksht with corresponding nums so that they line up by the same nums in another wksht in excel?

Tags: excel

This is a follow up question to my question earlier:

I have some date and time values in one worksheet - sheet 1- for the numbers

```
101  03June2017 09:00    
102  03June2017 09:10    
103  03June2017 09:15
```

The same numbers 101-103 appear in another worksheet - sheet 2- of the same Excel workbook, but they may be repetitive along with the dates appearing next to them.

```
101 03June2017    
101 03June2017    
101 03June2017    
102 03June2017    
102 03June2017    
102 03June2017    
103 03June2017    
103 03June2017    
103 03June2017
```

How can I use a formula to match the times from `sheet 1` to the numbers in `sheet 2` when they are repeating with the dates so that the times  line up correctly as per the number and date instead of copying them manually?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Scott, I am new to excel, and a bit confused on how to use the vlookup shown in the answer of the existing question. Can i get some clarity here?. your help is appreciated a lot, if you are able.

Comment: There are many options in the answer given.  I would go with the SUMIFS() route myself. `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A,a1,Sheet1!B:B,B1)`